# I need to change one value to the next down a list (up to n amount) if said cell becomes blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I currently am writing an excel formula for identifying different values with a common cost center, however, I need this formula to be able to go down a list of different cost centers and once it runs out of one value, it changes to the next.

For example, it goes down 3 different values for cost center 130, however, once it hits N/A or "" i need it to change the formula to the next cost center (140), then 150, then 160, etc, down the list, and repeat for n amount of times until theres no more cost centers to go.

If anyone knows what can i change or add to make this possible, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is my current formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E$10&ROW()-42,'Data'!$A:$AC,MATCH(C$46,$A$46:$AC$46,0),0),"")
```

I thought about applying a switch command to the formula however i either unsuccessfully implemented it, or it does not work for this current scenario.

Let me know if you have any other ideas

Comment: posting screenshot of at least part of our data structure would help, since base on your description alone is quite difficult to understand what exactly you try to get

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone has a similar situation like this.

A formula was not required, the answer to what i needed was much simpler, the option "advanced filter" was able to fulfill my need.

Advanced filter is capable of selecting a list of data and use it to filter by unique values (which you can define) and be able to change it with the click of a button.

Thank you.